# ./xxx.scss. Required module not found

Tags: flowtype

I am having trouble with scss module imports when I am running flow check. I have tried out various approaches including

.flowconfig

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='scss' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-typed/stub/css-module.js'
```

and I have

```
// @flow
type CSSModule = { [key: string]: string }
const emptyCSSModule: CSSModule = {}
export default emptyCSSModule
```

in the css-module.js. Do you know why it's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I had a similar issue when trying to use `.styl` files for stylus.

You might be able to solve this issue by doing the following which had worked for me:

1. Remove the `css-module.js` file.
2. Remove that `module.name_mapper.extension` line that you have in your **.flowconfig**
3. Add the following to the `[options]` in your **.flowconfig**:

---

```
module.file_ext=.js
module.file_ext=.jsx
module.file_ext=.json
module.file_ext=.scss
```